# Indexing a function result

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Having a function resolving into a list:

```
IntegerDigits[19835193751, 2^8, 8]
> {0,0,0,4,158,69,9,151}
```

Its result can be indexed fine like this:

```
IntegerDigits[19835193751, 2^8, 8][[5]]
> 158
```

But when symbolics are involved, all hell breaks loose:

```
IntegerDigits[q, 2^8, 8][[1]]
> q

IntegerDigits[q, 2^8, 8][[2]]
> 256

IntegerDigits[q, 2^8, 8][[3]]
> 8

IntegerDigits[q, 2^8, 8][[0]]
> IntegerDigits
```

I understand what happens and why, but how could I explain to the program that I want the results indexed, not an object which holds the function and its arguments?

*Added*: I suppose it boils down to defining a resolution order for functions - `Part` should stay deferred until its argument becomes a `List`. Still figuring out an implementation though.

Comment: Look up [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed)

Comment: @CarlWoll good point, but this feature is relatively new, older versions don't have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In M10+ you can use [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed). In versions before M10, you could do:

```
indexed[l_List, n_Integer?NonNegative] := l[[n]]
```

For example:

```
expr = indexed[IntegerDigits[q, 256, 8], 5]

expr /. q->13943312222
```

> indexed[IntegerDigits[q, 256, 8], 5]
>
> 63